# Prove that either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)$ is an odd function.

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a derivable function at $x = 0$ and $$f(\frac{x+y}{k})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{k} $$ $k\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0,2\}$. Prove that either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)$ is an odd function.

Could someone give me help me with this problem. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Take $x=-y$ to get $kf\left(0\right) = f(x) + f(-x)$. Now divide by $2x$ and take $x\to 0$. The right hand side limit can be related to $f'(0)$ and for the left hand side limit to exist we get a constraint on $f(0)$.

Comment: btw the argument above is only needed for $k=2$.

Answer (score 4):

Using $k=1$, we get $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. It follows that $f(0)=0$. Then 
$$
0=f(x+(-x))=f(x)+f(-x),
$$
so $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f$ is odd.